# dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction() Auto convert type of return?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a interface:

```
    public interface IDbTransactionManagerEF: IDbTransactionManager, IDbContextTransaction
    {
    }
```

And when I call

```
IDbContextTransaction contextTransaction = this._dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction()
```

I expect got a value which is a type of `IDbContextTransaction`. But type of `contextTransaction` variable is `SqlServerTransaction`.

How can I convert `contextTransaction` to `IDbTransactionManagerEF`.

I did:

```
 this._CommandContextEF.DbTransaction = (IDbTransactionManagerEF)contextTransaction;
```

But it didn't work, the error shows:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerTransaction' to type 'ChainOfCommand.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbTransactionManagerEF'.

After some Chat with @Nannanas, I tried this solution but not work:

```
var transactionConverted = (IDbContextTransaction)contextTransaction;
                       this._CommandContextEF.DbTransaction = (IDbTransactionManagerEF)transactionConverted;
```

The error message:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerTransaction' to type 'ChainOfCommand.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbTransactionManagerEF'.
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  What are you trying to acomplish?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft i want convert type of contextTransaction to IDbTransactionManagerEF.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft The code show that the type of contextTransaction  is IDbContextTransaction. In runtime the type of contextTransaction  is SqlServerTransaction. How .NET do that?

Comment: @quanchinhong what you are trying to do is not possible - `IDbTransactionManagerEF` is an interface you defined yourself and therefore it is not (and cannot be) implemented by `SqlServerTransaction` therefore a cast will always fail.

Comment: @Nannanas I know SqlServerTransaction doesnt implement *IDbTransactionManagerEF*, but The type of contextTransaction variable is IDbContextTransaction and IDbTransactionManagerEF inherited IDbContextTransaction . So Why I cannot cast IDbContextTransaction  to  IDbTransactionManagerEF and Why in runtime the type of contextTransaction become SqlServerTransaction.

Comment: @quanchinhong you just gave the answer to yourself: `IDbTransactionManagerEF` **implements** `IDbContextTransaction` (there is no inheritance for interfaces) - so every `IDbTransactionManagerEF` is also an `IDbContextTransaction`, therefore a cast from `IDbTransactionManagerEF` to `IDbContextTransaction` would work. But the statement is not true the other way round - not every `IDbContextTransaction` is also an  `IDbTransactionManagerEF` and thats why you cannot cast.

Comment: @quanchinhong additionally: if a cast is possible always depends on the underlying class (not the interface). So if the returned value is of type `SqlServerTransaction` as cast to `IDbTransactionManagerEF` is not possible because `SqlServerTransaction` does not implement it.

Comment: @Nannanas The SqlServerTransaction type have not inherited IDbContextTransaction, why SqlServerTransaction is still assignable to IDbContextTransaction

Comment: @quanchinhong where do you get the information from that it does not **implement** (again: there is no such thing as inheriting from an interface) `IDbContextTransaction`? Maybe it does not directly implement the interface but a base class already implements it.

Comment: @Nannanas Oh I got it. *SqlServerTransaction* implement *RelationalTransaction* and *RelationalTransaction* implement *IDbContextTransaction*. I got it, you are right

Comment: @Nannanas I tried ```var transactionConverted = (IDbContextTransaction)contextTransaction;
                       this._CommandContextEF.DbTransaction = (IDbTransactionManagerEF)transactionConverted;``` But not work

Comment: @Nannanas I cannot convert SqlServerTransaction  to IDbContextTransaction. I did ```var transactionConverted = (IDbContextTransaction)contextTransaction;``` But In runtime the type of contextTransaction still SqlServerTransaction . I dont know why

Comment: @quanchinhong contextTransaction is already of type `IDbContextTransaction` (you even declared the variable like that) so casting it to `IDbContextTransaction` and assinging it to `transactionConverted ` does absolutley nothing (you just have the same variable twice now).

As I said before: What you are trying to do is **not possible** at all. The underlying type of the object is `SqlServerTransaction` and you **cannot change** that - no matter how much casting you do (casting just changes how the compiler sees the object but does not change the actual implementation).

Comment: And because `SqlServerTransaction` does not implement `IDbTransactionManagerEF` the cast you are trying to make will **never be possible**.

Additionaly I do not really understand what you are trying to achive by casting the object to a different interface and then assigning it (again because casting does not change the actual implementation)

Comment: @Nannanas I want to manager transaction in multiple Database driver such as EntityFramework and Dappper, Mongodb ... so on